# Perforce - creating and editing a change list

Tags: python, command-line, perforce, p4python

My goal is to automatically create a changelist. I do this by running though some edit commands and submitting the change list at the end of the code sequence.

I run through all my commands in this similar order:

```
//Open all files in folder for edit in default changelist
p4.run(("edit", Folder + "..."))

//Move all files from default changelist to new changelist
changespec = p4.fetch_change()
changespec["Description"] = "test"
p4.save_change(changespec)

//Get changelist number
ChangeListNum = p4.run(("changes", "-m1", Folder + "..."))[0]['change']

//Run checks on files before submitting
p4.run("reconcile", "-a", "-c", ChangeListNum, Folder + "...")
p4.run("resolve", "-at", "-c", ChangeListNum, Folder + "...")
p4.run("revert", "-a", "-c", ChangeListNum, Folder + "...")

//Submit change list
p4.run("submit", "-c", ChangeListNum, "-f", "revertunchanged")
```

Now, during my checks and submit, my logger reports this error:

*"Change #CL_Number is already committed."*

I sure it has to do something with mixing the P4Python functions like `p4.fetch_change()` and `p4.run()`. I'm not sure how to resolve this issue, but below is one solution I tried.

I tried changing the block of code:

```
changespec = p4.fetch_change()
changespec["Description"] = "test"
self.p4.save_change(changespec)
```

to this:

```
p4.run("change", "-i", "<", "P4ChangeList.txt")
```

That command reads in the change list txt i made, and creates a new changelist with those parameters. However, it only works in the cmd and not in the python command.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: There seems to be some copy/paste issues here. Why do you once pass a tuple to `p4.run` and every other time pass a bunch of arguments? Why do you use `p4` everywhere except the line where you use `self.p4`? Why are you doing `ChangeListNumber = ...` then later referring to it as `ChangeListNum`?

What do you mean by "mixing P4Python functions and the cmd function?" I don't see any cmd function?

Comment: opps ill fix that. These parts of the code exist in different parts of the python, which i over looked. I edited the mixing of P4Python functions part. In most of the application, I used `p4.run()` to execute perforce commands like in the cmd. Then when creating the changelist i used `p4.fetchchange()` which im thinking is giving me the logging error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the script is that this command:

```
//Get changelist number
ChangeListNum = p4.run(("changes", "-m1", Folder + "..."))[0]['change']
```

will give you the latest **submitted** change, because you provided a filespec (meaning the output is limited to changelists with **submitted** revisions matching that specification).

Even leaving that aside, structuring the script this way leaves you vulnerable to a race condition where another user might create a changelist in between when you create yours and when you run that query.  What you'd want to do instead would be to capture the changelist number at the time that you save it (another user won't be allowed to "steal" your change number so this is 100% safe from that sort of race).

But leaving THAT aside, your script is making something very complicated out of something very simple, which is "submit the files I changed" -- since the script doesn't modify any files itself I assume you've already edited the files before running it.  Throw the whole script out and replace it with this:

```
# Open all changed files in the default changelist.
p4.run_reconcile(Folder + "...")
# Submit the default changelist.
p4.run_submit("-d", "test")
```

and you're done!

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect!